# How to record the Successful Login with Spring Security 4

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC 4 Application using Spring Security 4. I am trying to record every successful login in my system. I have already tried the `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` solution but it didn't work.

I am using Spring MVC 4 and Spring Security 4

My login form code is:

```
<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl" />
            <form action="${loginUrl}" method='POST'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Login</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"><input id="send" type="submit" value="Login"></th>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                        <div class="loginError" style="text-align: center">Invalid username and/or password. Please try again.</div>
                    </c:if>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I finally got it.

First create a `CustomLoginHandler`

```
public class CustomLoginSucessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            // record login success of user
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

    }
```

Later declare if in your `Configuration Bean`

In my case I did this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().successHandler(new CustomLoginSucessHandler());
}
```

And now when I Login I can do whatever I want inside my `CustomLoginHandler`